# Cant remove emissionobject from orthographic view camera

Tags: camera, orthographic

I have a camera placed in front of an emission object, but when I enter orthographic view in the camera, the object appears in from the camera thus blocking my scene? Ive turned off the emission objects camera ray visibility too?

Comment: Could you clarify the question, maybe with some screenshots of the scene and what you actually see in the camera? When "camera placed in front of an emission object" I would expect it to see the object thus the object is expected to appear in front of everything behind it. What shading mode do you use do preview the scene?

Answer (score 1):

I was using numpad 5 instead of making the camera othrographic - my mistake, thanks for the quick response!